# How to update a column name which is named after a date in SQL

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE studentattendance
JOIN studentdetails using(matricno)
JOIN studentModules using (matricno)
SET 05/12/15 = 1
WHERE cardUid = '01545695'
```

Hey hows it going, I'm having trouble updating a column in my database, the column is called '05/12/15' because it's named after a date. However I'm having trouble updating it with SQL because the syntax is wrong.

How do I update it as it seems to be having trouble with the forward slashes. I've tried single quotes and square brackets but they don't work

Thanks

Comment: use backtick to quote the column name. ` `05/12/15` `

Comment: What bansi said ^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `backticks` permits you to use alternative characters.

```
SET `05/12/15` = 1
```

query :-

```
UPDATE studentattendance
JOIN studentdetails using(matricno)
JOIN studentModules using (matricno)
SET `05/12/15` = 1
WHERE cardUid = '01545695'
```